# Custom function to get the location of dataframe value

Tags: python, dataframe

This question is more or less similar to my last question, but with little difference i have a DF

```
Index   Batch   Name    List Name
0        1      Jon     Adam
1           
2        2      Adam    Sam
3                       Chris
4        3      Voges   Jon
5           
6        4      Jon     Voges
```

I want to search the Batch number of each values in list name i.e for Adam,Sam,Chris,Jon and Voges. I want another DF from this as below

```
Index   Batch   Name    List Name   BatchNames
0        1      Jon     Adam        Adam(2)
1               
2        2      Adam    Sam         Sam(2)
3                       Chris       Chris(2)
4        3     Voges    Jon         Jon(1,4)
5               
6        4     Jon      Voges       Voges(3)
```

I want to pick each list name and search the corresponding batch number they have for in the Name, i.e `Jon` exists in `1 and 4` and so on. But if a name in Listname  does not exist in Name, it should pick the corresponding Batch number which is close to it, for example, `Sam` does not exist in Name, but it is close to `Batch 2`, and so does the `Chris`. Basically whatever is present between the batches belongs to the lowest batch number. How can i write a custom function for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def custom_function(df):
    # Forward fill the Batch number
    df_Batch = df.Batch.copy()
    df.Batch.ffill(inplace=True)
    df.Batch = df.Batch.astype(int)
    # Make a new dataframe where we first get batches for the name column
    # and append batches for the list name column, there we be duplicates so we keep the first entry
    a = df.groupby('Name').Batch.apply(tuple).append(df.groupby('List Name').Batch.apply(tuple)).reset_index().groupby('index').first()
    # Create a series which concatenates the Batch number and List Name
    b = pd.Series(a.index.astype(str) + a.Batch.astype(str), index=a.index).replace(',','', regex=True).replace(' ',',',regex=True)
    # undo the forward fill (replace with original columns)
    df.Batch = df_Batch
    # join the series we just made to the dataframe
    return df.merge(b.to_frame().rename_axis('List Name'), how='left', on='List Name', suffixes=['', 'Names']).fillna('')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Batch':[1,np.nan,2,np.nan,3,np.nan,4], 'Name':['Jon',np.nan, 'Adam',np.nan, 'Voges',np.nan, 'Jon'], 'List Name':['Adam', np.nan, 'Sam', 'Chris', 'Jon', np.nan, 'Voges']})
# Out[122]: 
#    Batch   Name List Name
# 0    1.0    Jon      Adam
# 1    NaN    NaN       NaN
# 2    2.0   Adam       Sam
# 3    NaN    NaN     Chris
# 4    3.0  Voges       Jon
# 5    NaN    NaN       NaN
# 6    4.0    Jon     Voges
custom_function(df)
# Out[131]: 
#   Batch   Name List Name BatchNames
# 0     1    Jon      Adam    Adam(2)
# 1                                  
# 2     2   Adam       Sam     Sam(2)
# 3                  Chris   Chris(2)
# 4     3  Voges       Jon   Jon(1,4)
# 5                                  
# 6     4    Jon     Voges   Voges(3)
```

Comment: I am getting an error 
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
**KeyError: 'List Name'**

Comment: Does ^ that work if you just copy and paste into a python shell/interpreter? If no, there could be some version issues and I would want to know which pandas/python version you're using. 

If it does work, could you please post the full traceback and/or a reproducible copy of the dataframe you're running the definition on (such that I could debug it)?

Comment: I ran the exact code u gave me and i am using python 3.6, even created the same DF as u have here and i got the above mentioned error

Comment: When I go to a [python3 emulator](https://repl.it/) and copy and paste that code, it runs as expected. What version of pandas are you using? i.e. what does `pip show pandas` return?

Comment: Version: 0.22.0

Comment: You are correct, after upgrading the pandas version this is working, thanks. What if i want to have a separate DF instead of merged

Comment: Instead of BatchNames, what should i do if want to have this output in ListName itself

Comment: Or just replace `df['List Name']` with `b` in the definition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173865/discussion-between-chris-and-cosmic-inquiry).